# Vcpkg has no effect on cloned project

Tags: c++, vcpkg

I have a github repository I created using libraries installed with vcpkg. Now when I switch to another machine with vcpkg installed with all libraries, it can't find the include directories.

When I create a new project in Visual Studio everything works fine and all the includes are working, but if I clone the github repository, it can't include any of the libraries.

I would like to be able to use the vcpkg installed libraries with cloned projcets as well if that's possible.

Comment: "if that's possible" - of course it's *possible*. It's only a matter of knowing how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after 2 days of fighting with vcpkg, trying to export NuGet packages and editing .vcxproj files, it turns out I have installed the x86 versions of the libraries and I just had to change to x86 in Visual Studio...